# Text Truncation In Grid With Dynamic Height

Tags: wpf

The height of this grid is adjustable and I need to be able to truncate the status one text while preserving the rule that the status three is always visible and status two always appears directly below status one.  I attempted to accomplish this by setting the VerticalAlignment of status 2 to top with no luck.

For example, notice when you change the height of 78 to 178, status 2 does not sit next to status one anymore.

```
<Grid Height="78"
      Width="167">

<Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <RowDefinition Height="*" />
    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
</Grid.RowDefinitions>

<Border x:Name="_itemBorder"
        Grid.RowSpan="3"
        Background="LightBlue" />

<TextBlock x:Name="_statusOneTextBlock"
           Grid.Row="0"
           Margin="5"
           Text="STATUS 1 Very long status one text"
           TextWrapping="Wrap"
           TextTrimming="CharacterEllipsis" />

<TextBlock x:Name="_statusTwoTextBlock"
           Grid.Row="1"
           Margin="5"
           Text="STATUS 2"
           VerticalAlignment="Top"
           TextTrimming="CharacterEllipsis" />

<TextBlock x:Name="_statusThreeTextBlock"
           Grid.Row="3"
           Margin="5"
           Text="STATUS 3"
           VerticalAlignment="Bottom"
           TextTrimming="CharacterEllipsis" />
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed using an InlineUIContainer within a TextBlock:

```
<Grid Height="68"
      Width="167">

<Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <RowDefinition Height="*" />
    <RowDefinition Height="23" />
</Grid.RowDefinitions>

<Border x:Name="_itemBorder"
        Grid.RowSpan="2"
        Background="LightBlue" />

<TextBlock Grid.Row="0">
<TextBlock x:Name="_statusOneTextBlock"
           Text="STATUS 1 Very long status one text"
           TextWrapping="Wrap"
           TextTrimming="CharacterEllipsis" />
<LineBreak />
<InlineUIContainer>
    <TextBlock x:Name="_statusTwoTextBlock"
               Text="STATUS 2"
               VerticalAlignment="Top"
               TextTrimming="CharacterEllipsis" />
</InlineUIContainer>
</TextBlock>

<TextBlock x:Name="_statusThreeTextBlock"
           Grid.Row="1"
           Text="STATUS 3"
           VerticalAlignment="Bottom"
           TextTrimming="CharacterEllipsis" />
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<Grid Height="178" 
  Width="167">

    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />

    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <Border x:Name="_itemBorder" 
    Grid.RowSpan="3" 
    Background="LightBlue" />

    <TextBlock x:Name="_statusOneTextBlock" 
       Grid.Row="0" 
       Margin="5" 
       Text="STATUS 1 Very long status one text" 
       TextWrapping="NoWrap" 
       TextTrimming="CharacterEllipsis" />

    <TextBlock x:Name="_statusTwoTextBlock" 
       Grid.Row="1" 
       Margin="5" 
       Text="STATUS 2" 
       VerticalAlignment="Top" 
       TextTrimming="CharacterEllipsis" />

    <TextBlock x:Name="_statusThreeTextBlock" 
       Grid.Row="2" 
       Margin="5" 
       Text="STATUS 3" 
       VerticalAlignment="Bottom" 
       TextTrimming="CharacterEllipsis" />
</Grid>
```

Comment: This does not work.  It looks like the grid height is no longer adjustable but fixed.